# Can I put my hard disk from Macbook pro Early 2009 in a Macbook Pro from 2011 without problems?

Tags: hard-drive, macbook

Can I put my hard disk (with OS) from a Macbook pro Early 2009 in a Macbook Pro from 2011 without problems? (And put the hard disk from this 2011 in the one from 2009 without any problems?)

Like software errors or other complicated things? I just want to re-use my hard disk without problems.

Comment: What version of OSX are you running on either one? I know you can start up from one plugged in on USB, but I don't know about internally as well

Comment: OS X 10.6
My concerns:
Software issues
Hardware issues

Answer (score 0):

With OSX 10.6, you should be able to pop the hard drive into another Mac and have it boot up with your current software and configuration running